# Changing categorical data to binary data is not reflected on the dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, kaggle

I am working through the Titanic competition.  This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/test.csv")

train['Sex'].replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1])
train['Embarked'].replace(['C', 'Q', 'S'], [1, 2, 3])

# Fill missing values in Age feature with each sex’s median value of Age
train['Age'].fillna(train.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform("median"), inplace=True)

linReg = LinearRegression()

data = train[['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Parch', 'Fare', 'Age']]

# implement train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, train['Survived'], test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Training the machine learning algorithm
linReg.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Checking the accuracy score of the model
accuracy = linReg.score(x_test, y_test)
print(accuracy*100, '%')
```

This line previously looked like this: `data = train[['Pclass', 'Parch', 'Fare', 'Age']]`, which ended up giving me an accuracy score of `19.5%`.  I realized that I didn't include sex so I went ahead and did this:

`data = train[['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Parch', 'Fare', 'Age']]`

Then, I got the following error:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'female'`

Here I realized that the changes that I've done to my `train['Sex']` and `train['Age']` did not reflect on the training and the testing of the model, which seems to be the reason why my model performed at `19.5%`.  How do I come across this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have converted the values into integer but you are not assigning it.

```
train['Sex'].replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1])
train['Embarked'].replace(['C', 'Q', 'S'], [1, 2, 3])
```

should be like that

```
train['Sex'] = train['Sex'].replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1])
train['Embarked'] = train['Embarked'].replace(['C', 'Q', 'S'], [1, 2, 3])
```

.

```
train['Age'].fillna(train.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform("median"), inplace=True)
```

this code is working without assigning the value just because you have used **inplace=True**. Otherwise you have to assign it back as I mentioned for "Sex" and "Embarked".

**scikit.preprocessing provides us various util methods for handling all such issues. Like *LabelEncoder, Imputer* for these purposes.**

***LabelEncoder*, will convert string to integer values whereas *Imputer*, will replace the missing value.**

Sample code for your reference:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer, LabelEncoder 
from collections import defaultdict 
data = train[['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Parch', 'Fare', 'Age']]
#If you want to convert all features string to integer 
d = defaultdict(LabelEncoder) 
data = data.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(x))

#Otherwise you can convert each feature strings separately as mentioned below 
encoder = LabelEncoder() 
data['Sex'] = encoder.fit_transform(data['Sex'])

imputer = Imputer(strategy="median") 
data = imputer.fit_transform(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your independent variables into numeric values. Normally for binary variables, we use the 0-1-encoding. Introduce a new variable called is_female. If the observation is a male person then give the variable the value $0$ and if the observation is a female person give the observation the value $1$.

If you have categorical variables like a city with three categories you will need to create additional variables. Imagine we have the possible values `["New York", "London", "Moskau"]`. Then you create three variables is_new_york, is_london, is_moskau.
If we have an observation from New York this will result in is_new_york=1, is_london=0, is_moskau=0. If we have an observation from London then the values will be is_new_york=0, is_london=1, is_moskau=0 and if we have an observation from Moskau then the values will be is_new_york=0, is_london=0, is_moskau=1. This type of encoding is called one-hot encoding. You can also have multiple cities. For example, if a person lives in Moskau and London then you can use is_new_york=0, is_london=1, is_moskau=1.

Comment: Yea but I've already done that.  I've changed my `Sex` variable to binaries of 0/1.